# Removing square brackets from hash array for value

Tags: ruby, hash

I am having a following hash array

```
A = [{"name" => ["xx"], "status" => ["true"]}, {"name" => ["yy"], "status" => ["true"]}
```

I tried following code to remove the square brackets

```
A.to_s.gsub("\\[|\\]", "")
```

also tried with code

```
p A.map { |hash| hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), hash| hash[k] = v.first } }
```

but its not working.

How I remove the square brackets to get following output

```
A = [{"name" => "xx", "status" => "true"}, {"name" => "yy", "status" => "true"}
```

Kindly assist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they're strings inside arrays, the [] is the representation Ruby does of it. Try accessing the first element for each key's value in those hashes:

```
a = [{"name" => ["xx"], "status" => ["true"]}, {"name" => ["yy"], "status" => ["true"]}]
p a.map { |hash| hash.transform_values(&:first) }
# [{"name"=>"xx", "status"=>"true"}, {"name"=>"yy", "status"=>"true"}]
```

Depending on your Ruby version, you might not have transform_values available. A simple `each_with_object` would work similarly in that case:

```
p a.map { |hash| hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), hash| hash[k] = v.first } }
# [{"name"=>"xx", "status"=>"true"}, {"name"=>"yy", "status"=>"true"}]
```

Comment: Its throwing me undefined method `transform_values' for {"name"=>["xx"], "status"=>["true"]}:Hash (NoMethodError)

Comment: Sorry, it depends in your Ruby version. See the updated answer.

Comment: I am not sure what I did wrong but its still giving me response as A = [{"name" => ["xx"], "status" => ["true"]}, {"name" => ["yy"], "status" => ["true"]}

Comment: Can you add your attempt to the question?

Comment: I have no problems with your code. [See](https://repl.it/@LagartoSeb/AmbitiousAnotherSearch).

Comment: Is it the issue with ruby 2.3?

Comment: It works with Ruby 2.3.1. Try renaming your A variable, which seems a constant, or just chaining the map.

Comment: Is there any gsub or regex pattern to do this? sorry for asking too much

Comment: Another way that does not use [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) (which made its debut  in v2.4) is the following: `a.map { |h| h.merge(h) { |_,o,_| o.is_a?(Array) && o.size==1 ? o.first : o } }`. This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to compute the value of each key that is present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys.

Comment: Didn't know much about transform_values @CarySwoveland, I thought about "the merge way" before, but discarded in favor of each_with_object. Glad to know that.